# SQL Server MAX and GROUP BY not playing nicely together

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, group-by, max, aggregate-functions

I have a T-SQL query of the form:

```
SELECT          f.fizz_name, b.buzz_version, fu.foo_name
FROM            fizz f
INNER JOIN      buzz b
ON              f.fizz_id = b.fizz_id
INNER JOIN      foo fu
ON              b.buzz_id = fu.buzz_id
WHERE           f.bar LIKE 'YES'
```

When I run this query I get the following results:

```
fizz_name   buzz_version    foo_name
====================================
Gamma       0.3.960         Test
Gamma       0.3.961         Test
Gamma       0.3.960         Test
Gamma       0.3.961         Test
Delta       0.3.2588        Test
Delta       0.3.2589        Test
Delta       0.3.2588        Test
Delta       0.3.2589        Test
Echo        2.2.38          Test
Echo        2.2.38          Test
```

The problem with this is that it contains a lot of entries that I don't care about. In reality I only care about the largest `buzz_version` for each `fizz` instance, in other words:

```
fizz_name   buzz_version    foo_name
====================================
Gamma       0.3.961         Test
Delta       0.3.2589        Test
Echo        2.2.38          Test
```

...because "*2.2.38*" is the latest/lexiconographically-highest `buzz_version` for `Echo`, and same for the other fizzes.

So I am trying to use `GROUP BY` in concert with `MAX` to fetch these values like so:

```
SELECT          f.fizz_name, MAX(b.buzz_version), fu.foo_name
FROM            fizz f
INNER JOIN      buzz b
ON              f.fizz_id = b.fizz_id
INNER JOIN      foo fu
ON              b.buzz_id = fu.buzz_id
WHERE           f.bar LIKE 'YES'
GROUP BY        b.buzz_version
```

But that gives me an error:

> Column 'fizz.fizz_name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Where am I going wrong, and why?

Comment: You are grouping by the aggregate in your query. You need to group by the scalar columns instead. In this case, group by f.fizz_name, fu.foo_name

Comment: Assuming your version number is a string, max can cause you issues if you're not careful with your data. For example 0.10.1 is smaller version than 0.2.1 because of alphabetical sorting

Comment: Thanks @SeanLange (+1) - put that in an answer and I'll give it a green check!

Comment: Thanks @JamesZ (+1) - yes the version is a string - any idea as to what I could use besides `MAX(...)` to get around this?!? Your example is perfect: I *would* want "0.10.1" to be "bigger" than "0.2.1", any ideas?

Comment: @smeeb If you can pad zeros to the version number, then max will work automatically, e.g 0.0010.1 vs 0.0002.1 works ok -- other alternatives probably require handling it as several separate numbers, which probably requires more complex handling f. ex. with cross apply + order by instead of max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are grouping by the aggregate in your query. You need to group by the scalar columns instead. In this case, group by f.fizz_name, fu.foo_name

Answer (score 1):

You want one result row per fizz_name, so you must group by fizz_name. You show MAX(b.buzz_version) with it and must decide which fu.foo_name to show. E.g.:

```
SELECT f.fizz_name, MAX(b.buzz_version), MAX(fu.foo_name)
FROM fizz f
INNER JOIN buzz b ON f.fizz_id = b.fizz_id
INNER JOIN foo fu ON b.buzz_id = fu.buzz_id
WHERE f.bar LIKE 'YES'
GROUP BY f.fizz_name;
```

Comment: Thanks @Thorsten Kettner (+1) - please see my comments with JamesZ, regarding the use of `MAX(...)` in this example. Any idea as to what would be a more appropriate aggregate? Thanks again!

Comment: You will have to format your version string. Let's say the first and second place is always one digit, but the third is anything from one to five digits: `MAX(stuff(b.buzz_version, 4, 1, replicate('0', 9 - len(b.buzz_version))))`. If the first and second number can be more than one digit too, then you need another string manipulation. Look up SQL Server string functions on this.